# How to convert list of strings to comma-seperated string in state machine input

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, state-machine, aws-step-functions

I'm working on writing state machine which will take input from lambda and run glue-job. Here's what I am trying to do:

- use `lambda` to get all tables dynamically which is `stage#1` in state machine, and
- pass all these table as comma-seperated values to glue job.

```yaml
  StartAt: GetTables

  GetTables:
    Type: Task
    Resource: ${get_tables_lambda_arn}
    Parameters:
      DatabaseName: ${source_glue_database_name}
    ResultSelector:
      SourceTables.$: $.tables
    ResultPath: $.Variables
    Next: RunJob

  RunJob:
    Type: Task
    Resource: arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync
    Parameters:
      JobName: ${glue_job_name}
      Arguments:
        "--destination_path": ${destination_path}
        "--run_date_iso_8601.$": $$.Execution.StartTime
        "--source_database": ${source_glue_database_name}
        "--source_tables.$": $.Variables.SourceTables
    ResultPath: null
    Next: Finish
```

Expected value for `--source_tables` field is `e.g. "table1,table2,table3"` . However, currently, `"--source_tables"` value is as `[\"table1\",\"table2\"]`.

I tried looking up intrinsic function([link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html)) but didn't work. Is there a way to convert it in state-machine?

Comment: `"{table1, table2, table3}"` is not valid JSON.  `"[\"table1\",\"table2\"]"` is valid JSON.

Comment: Why not write the logic in Lambda and finsih your task in a workflow as opposed to passing off to a GLUE job

Comment: @smac2020: It's being used across projects and I can't change it in lambda. Was wondering if something can be done in state-machine.

Comment: I would look at writing at all in a state machine via Lambda. A step machine is a sequence of Lambda functions.  Only drawback of using Lambda is if you dataset is so large - it will execeed max Lambda timeout of 15 mins